# Can't seem to get Bundler to run properly on Rails App server using Capistrano to deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, bundler, capistrano3

I've been using Rails for a couple of months now and made a small app that I'm trying to deploy with Capistrano. The problem is that when I run

```
$ cap production deploy
```

the deployment appears to run correctly except for the following 3 errors:

```
DEBUG [764d7f01] Running /usr/bin/env [ -L /var/www/rally_app/releases/20150513103829/public/assets ] as deploy@255.255.255.255
DEBUG [764d7f01] Command: [ -L /var/www/rally_app/releases/20150513103829/public/assets ]
DEBUG [764d7f01] Finished in 3.347 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).

DEBUG [929898d3] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d /var/www/rally_app/releases/20150513103829/public/assets ] as deploy@255.255.255.255
DEBUG [929898d3] Command: [ -d /var/www/rally_app/releases/20150513103829/public/assets ]
DEBUG [929898d3] Finished in 4.065 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).


DEBUG [8917ed02] Running /usr/bin/env ls /var/www/rally_app/releases/20150513103829/public/assets/.sprockets-manifest* as deploy@255.255.255.255
DEBUG [8917ed02] Command: cd /var/www/rally_app/releases/20150513103829 && ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.2.1 /usr/bin/env ls /var/www/rally_app/releases/20150513103829/public/assets/.sprockets-manifest* )
DEBUG [8917ed02]        ls: cannot access /var/www/rally_app/releases/20150513103829/public/assets/.sprockets-manifest*: No such file or directory
DEBUG [8917ed02] Finished in 3.716 seconds with exit status 2 (failed).
```

Also, it appears Bundler doesn't run properly, because even though the App is supposed to use PostgreSQL in production, Passenger gives an error about sqlite3 stating:

```
Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)
  /var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord
```

I've changed the RailsEnv to development only temporarily to view these logs.  If it will help to post more information from the Phusion Passenger logs, I am happy to post.  Please let me know.

I'm Linux server admin savvy but I'm a complete Rails/Passenger/rbenv/Capistrano noob, so please consider this in your replies. :)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Alexis

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with "I've changed the RailsEnv to development only temporarily to view these logs." The problem is Rails reacts very differently (loads different gems etc) when you specify another environment. (That might also be the reason for the sqlite3 error).

Comment: Hi @wpp, I added 'RailsEnv development' to /usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2_2/rallyapp/**/rails.conf on my server to temporarily enable the site to show Passenger debugging info when loading the home page.  That showed the error starting with with "Specified 'sqlite3'...".  The other errors I posted above were from the terminal when running 'cap production deploy' on the server while the environment was production.

Comment: Ok so I'd ignore the sqlite error. You could try running `cap deploy:cold  -d` to get more helpful output. But I'm not great with capistrano, sry.

Comment: Thanks @wpp for the tip re. **cap deploy cold**.  I looked at http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/cold-start/ and created and ran all the cap tasks on that page with no errors, so I must be getting close now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got past this problem by looking over my deploy.rb and uncommenting

```
set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml')

set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system')
```

I think absence of the second line is was what caused the errors.  I also manually created the above two yaml files on my server.

I'm now getting an error from rails about PostgreSQL, but that's progress as it's a higher level issue, so my question above is solved.  Thanks for pointers @wpp.